# I can not create instace of DBContext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have model:

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [UniqueDepartmentName]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

And DBcontext:

```
public class InstituteContext : DbContext
{
    public InstituteContext (DbContextOptions<InstituteContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().HasIndex(p => p.Name).IsUnique();
    }
    public DbSet<Institute.Models.Department> Department { get; set; }
}
```

As you see property "NAME" i make unique. 
For validation i create My validation Attribute:

```
 public class UniqueDepartmentName : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var db = new InstituteContext();
    }
}
```

But i can not create instance of InstituteContext, because constructor need parameters. 
How i can create instance of InstituteContext? Or what should i pass to constructor in parameters?

Comment: Just add a parameterless constructor to`InstituteContext`. If you need anything configured, the `OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder)` method will be called so you can do some configuration there. **OR**, when you create an instance of `InstituteContext`, provide it with the `DbContextOptions<InstituteContext>`. You are not doing anything with the `DbContextOptions<InstituteContext>` so a parameterless constructor will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class UniqueDepartmentName : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var connectionString = "Your ConnectionString"
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<InstituteContext>()
                         .UseSqlServer(new SqlConnection(connectionString)).Options;

        using (var dbContext = new BloggingContext(options))
        {
           // Do necessary staffs here with dbContext
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DbContextOptions method is in the wrong place, your constructor can be empty, and you need to add the method `OnConfiguring`, which receives the DbContextOptions.
Something like:

```
public DbSet<Department> Department { get; private set; }

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) {
    // In my case I'm passing the connection string in this method below
    options.UseSqlServer("Data Source=DATABASEIP;Initial Catalog=DATABASETABLE;" +
        "User ID=USER;Password=PASSWORD");
}
```